# Как правильно прописать пути на сервере Tomcat для работы сервлета?

Tags: сервлеты, tomcat

Добрый день! Помогите с таким вопросом: на сервере tomcat есть html форма, с которой данные должны попасть на сервлет. Сервлет выдаст некую информацию на экран. Структура - в папке webapps лежит папка it, в ней сама форма index.html + WEB-INF. Сервлет jd013.Form. Что должно быть написано в форме <form action = "?"> и в web.xml чтобы работало?